# reading from file containing accented characters in nodejs

Tags: node.js, utf-8, maxmind

So i am parsing a large csv file and pushing the results into mongo.

The file is [maxminds city database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite). It has all kinds of fun utf8 characters. I am still getting (?) symbols in some city names. Here is how I am reading the file:

(using csv node module)

```
csv().from.stream(fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'datafiles', 'cities.csv'), {
    flags: 'r',
    encoding: 'utf8'
})).on('record', function(row,index){
.. uninteresting code to add it to mongodb
});
```

What could i be doing wrong here?
I am getting things like this in mongo: Ch�teauguay, Canada

**EDIT**:

i tried using a different lib to read the file:

```
lazy(fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'datafiles', 'cities.csv'), {
    flags: 'r',
    encoding: 'utf8',
    autoClose: true
  }))
    .lines
    .map(String)
    .skip(1) // skips the two lines that are iptables header
    .map(function (line) {
      console.log(line);
    });
```

it produces the same bad results:
154252,"PA","03","Capellan�a","",8.3000,-80.5500,,
154220,"AR","01","Villa Espa�a","",-34.7667,-58.2000,,

Comment: If you just read the file from `fs.createReadStream` with `utf-8`, is it corrupt?  Could the csv module be mangling it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

turns out maxmind encodes their stuff in latin1.

this works:

```
  var iconv  = require('iconv-lite')
  lazy(fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'datafiles', 'cities.csv')))
    .lines
    .map(function(byteArray) {
      return iconv.decode(byteArray, 'latin1');
    })
    .skip(1) // skips the two lines that are iptables header
    .map(function (line) {
   //WORKS
```

Comment: latin1 also works when decoding accented characters from buffer data. Thank you.